# camera2 api crashing on android 8.1.0

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have used camera2 API to record the video, it is working absolutely fine but having problem only on android 8.1.0

throwing the following exception :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CaptureCallbackHolder.getRequest(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onResultReceived(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1923)
   at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim$CameraCallbackThread$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:323)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```